# Increasing the Vertical Space Following a TOC Chapter Entry Only When Followed by a Section Entry

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, pdftex, tocloft, vertical-spacing

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage  

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace{4pt}} 
%\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace{0pt}} 

\cftpagenumbersoff{section}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\contentsname{{\color{red} \hfill Table of Contents \hfill}}
\tableofcontents


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chap. 1. }}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chap. 2. }}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chap. 3. }}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chap. 4. }}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chap. 5. }}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 5.1 \color{blue}{\textbf{\textit{``I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.''}---Thomas A. Edison}}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\vspace{10pt} Section. \color{blue}{\textbf{\textit{``I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.''}---Thomas A. Edison}}}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

I would like to increase the space between the Chap. 5 entry and the Section entry beneath.

If I increase the 4pt in `\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace{4pt}}`, that will increase the space following all of the Chapter entries---which I don't want.

So, I figured that I would try to selectively add a vertical space of 10pt in the following manner:

`\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\vspace{10pt} Section. \ldots\}`; but, when I do that, I get

[image]

which, for some reason (I don't know why), a 10pt space seems to have been added after the first line, and not before it, in the section entry.

QUESTION: How may I either (1), selectively add vertical space in the TOC prior to a particular section entry being posted (which will always follow a chapter entry); or, (2) How may I universally increase the 4pt space after a chapter entry, to say 10pt, *only* when followed by a section entry? (I'm not sure (2) is possible, though.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the tag

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}
```

After the fifth chapter starts, i.e.,

```
\chapter{Chapter 5}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}
```

Comment: Yes. That seems to work nicely. Thank you.